# React Hook useRef return style property as null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am working on a modal in which I have to access the id property of an HTML element to change its display property. I have used the ***useRef Hook*** to attain it but got the following errors.

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

**Modal.js:-**  The code is of ***1000*** Lines so I am sharing only the part where I have used it.

```js
    const [isAddProjectClicked, setisAddProjectClicked] = useState(true);
const [isAddProjectClicked, setisAddProjectClicked] = useState(true);
const addProjectModal = useRef(null);

const closeAddProjectModal = () => {
 addProjectModal.current.style.display = 'block';
};

const renderAddProject = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="task-accordion" ref={addProjectModal} style={{ display: 'none' }}>
                    <i
                        className="fa fa-close close-icon"
                        id="closeIconn"
                        onClick={() => closeAddProjectModal()}
                        aria-hidden="true"
                    ></i>

                    <h4>ADD Project</h4>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <textarea
                            id="textAreaAddProject"
                            type="text"
                            style={{ height: '30vh' }}
                            placeholder="Project Title"
                            name="Title"
                            className="form-control"
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                setprojectTitle(e.target.value);
                            }}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-12 add-mupps-button">
                        <button type="submit" onClick={() => postProjectApiCall()}>
                            Save
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };


<div className="col-sm-8 last-div padding-0">
                
    {isAddProjectClicked && renderAddProject()}
                
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the line that is trying to access `.style`? Also, you shouldn't change an element's style like that; use a state instead and pass that to the `style` attribute.

Comment: changes have been made , You can now review it and suggest me if there is any problem.

Comment: @KunalKumar is there any specific reason to not use React state for this? Becuase that's why we use React, to do UI updates in a very optimize & efficient manner than DOM.

Comment: @yushan I was provided with this code as I am an intern. So, I would like to get the resources to fix this using the use state. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's how to display and hide a modal using the parent's state: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-nightingale-098lx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the visibility of your model by creating a state like this.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isAddProjectClicked, setisAddProjectClicked] = useState(true);
  const [addProjectModal, openAddProjectModal] = useState("none"); // creating the state

  const renderAddProject = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="task-accordion" style={{ display: addProjectModal }}> {/* Set that as display's property value */}
          <i
            className="fa fa-close close-icon"
            id="closeIconn"
            onClick={() => openAddProjectModal("block")}
            aria-hidden="true"
          ></i>

          <h4>ADD Project</h4>
          <div className="form-group">
            <textarea
              id="textAreaAddProject"
              type="text"
              style={{ height: "30vh" }}
              placeholder="Project Title"
              name="Title"
              className="form-control"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-12 add-mupps-button">
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isAddProjectClicked && renderAddProject()}
      <button onClick={() => openAddProjectModal("block")}>Click Me</button>
      {/* Change the state using any event you want */}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if you need further support.

Answer (score 0):

If the component is not mounted, the ref is null so you should add condition to it

```
const closeAddProjectModal = () => {
   if(addProjectModal.current) {
       addProjectModal.current.style.display = 'block';
   }
};
```

or just use optional chaining

```
const closeAddProjectModal = () => {
    addProjectModal.current?.style.display = 'block';
};
```

Comment: Good point, but why would that function be called if the modal isn't mounted? It's the close button's click handler.

Comment: Maybe it's already placed in the execution context

Answer (score 0):

Use react to set the style:

```
function AddProjectModal(props) {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(visible);

    return <div style={{display: visible?'block':'none'}}>
        <button onClick={()=>setVisible(false)}>
        Close
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

No need for a ref to change the style or a class